# Como manipular linhas de txt no php?

Tags: php

Bom estou desenvolvendo um chat com base em documento.html, porem gostaria de estar manipulando e limitando o numero de linhas:
segue meu codigo atual

```
 <?php
 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
 $linha = $nome.' - '.$mensagem.'<br>';
 $arquivo = file('chatlog.htm');
 array_push($arquivo, $linha);
 file_put_contents('chatlog.htm', $arquivo);
 ?>
```

DUVIDAS: 
A minha primeira duvida é como fazer com que o meu codigo sera inserido em linhas? Atualmente o arquivo esta sendo escrito como frases

EX como esta: Joao - Ola br Jose - OI br Joao - tudo bem? br...
EX como gostaria: 
linha1: Joao - Ola 
linha2: Jose - OI 
linha3: Joao - tudo bem? 
...

A segunda duvida é como posso excluir tudo antes ou apos a EX: decima linha.

Comment: Porque não salvar como txt, já que você trata como arquivo de texto?

Comment: Outra coisa, adicione um `\n` logo ao lado do `<br>`, assim creio que seja suficiente pra salvar linha a linha.

Comment: alterei para txt porem o \n esta saindo na impressao do codigo

Comment: Altere para `"<br>\n"`. Lembrando que o `<br>` é tag html, a nao ser que abra o arquivo no navegador, ele será ignorado.

Comment: continua escrevendo \n na impressao e no txt tambem nao esta saltando linha no arquivo txt

Comment: Bem eu criei esse mini tutorial a muitos anos atrás, ele fala como transformar [Banco de Dados com TXT](http://forum.wmonline.com.br/topic/84135-banco-de-dados-com-txt/) da uma lida talvez ajude a fazer o que quer.

Comment: Salvar com PHP_EOL não ajudaria? PHP_EOL pula uma linha ao escrever no arquivo.

Answer (score 2):

Para inserir em linhas ao invés de usar `file_put_contents` use `fwrite` (ou `fput`) e será necessário usar `PHP_EOL` para quebras de linhas.

> Nota é recomendável converter a mensagem em entidades html para evitar ataques [XSS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) por exemplo, para isso use `htmlspecialchars`.

Um exemplo para gravação seria:

```
<?php
$nome = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nome']);
$mensagem = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mensagem']);
$linha = $nome . ' - ' . $mensagem . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

$handle = fopen('chatlog.html', 'a'); //O 'a' põe o ponteiro no final, assim a grava no final do arquivo
fwrite($handle, $linha);
fclose($handle);
```

Notei que você está gravando tudo em um `.html` isto quer dizer que talvez a leitura seja feita diretamente no HTML, talvez um iframe ou ajax que fica fazendo reload de `chatlog.html`, isto funciona, mas quanto maior o arquivo mais demorado da página responder.

> **Nota: os passos a seguir são opcionais e não tem haver com o problema, considere como uma dica apenas, sendo totalmente opcional**, este processo descrito é preferencial para se trabalhar com Ajax ou algo semelhante e manipulação de DOM por javascript.

Uma maneira de o arquivo pode ser usando `fopen`, `feof` e `fgets` (`fgets` lê linha a linha diferente do `fread` que lê por tamanho), será necessário `$_SESSION` ou *cookies normais*.

O arquivo de leitura php deve ser algo como (de um nome como chatreader.php):

```
<?php
session_start();

//Verifica a última linha que o usuário leu
if (empty($_SESSION['currentLine'])) {
    //Se é a primeira vez que o usuário acessa então a leitura começa do '0'.
    $_SESSION['currentLine'] = 0;
}

$current = $_SESSION['currentLine'];
$i = 0;

$handle = fopen('chatlog.html', 'r');
while (false === foef($handle)) {
    ++$i; //Soma para contar as linhas

    //Se $i for maior que $current então significa que a linha não foi lida
    if ($i > $current) {
        echo fgets($handle);
    }
}

$_SESSION['currentLine'] = $i; //Grava a ultima posição de leitura
```

O javascript ficaria algo como:

```
<div id="conversa"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function xhr() {
    var xmlhttp = false;

    if (XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(ee){}
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}

function chatReader(target) {
    var x = xhr();

    if (x === false) { 
        return;
    }

    x.open("GET", "chatreader.php?_=" + (new Date().getTime()), true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (x.readyState === 4){
            if (x.status === 200) {
                var nd = document.createElement("div");
                nd.innerHTML = x.responseText;
                target.appendChild(nd);
            } else {
                console.log("Erro no servidor", x.status);
            }

            setTimeout(function() {
                chatReader(target);
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
    x.send(null);  
}

window.onload = function() {
    var conversa = document.getElementById("conversa");
    if (conversa) {
        chatReader(conversa);
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom eu até gostaria de aprender a utilizar essas funcoes pelo que vi era baseado em arrays no txt, mais pesquisando achei esse script de um projeto de uma chat que me caiu como uma luva, pois fazia o que queria so que de outra maneira segue o codigo e os creditos

https://www.metachris.com/projects/most-simple-ajax-chat-ever/

```
<?php

 /**

  * Author: chris at linuxuser.at

  * Licence: MIT

  */



 $fn = "chat.txt";

 $maxlines = 20;



 $nick_maxlength = 10;



 /* Set this to a minimum wait time between posts (in sec) */

 $waittime_sec = 0;



 /* spam keywords */

 $spam[] = "cum";

 $spam[] = "dick";



 /* IP's to block */

 $blockip[] = "72.60.167.89";



 /* spam, if message IS exactly that string */

 $espam[] = "ajax";



 $msg = $_REQUEST["m"];

 $n = $_REQUEST["n"];



 if ($waittime_sec > 0) {

     $lastvisit = $_COOKIE["lachatlv"];

     setcookie("lachatlv", time());



     if ($lastvisit != "") {

         $diff = time() - $lastvisit;

         if ($diff < $waittime_sec) { die(); }

     }

 }



 if ($msg != "") {

     if (strlen($msg) < 2) { die(); }

     if (strlen($msg) > 3) {

         /* Smilies are ok */

         if (strtoupper($msg) == $msg) { die(); }

     }

     if (strlen($msg) > 150) { die(); }

     if (strlen($msg) > 15) {

         if (substr_count($msg, substr($msg, 6, 8)) > 1) { die(); }

     }



     foreach ($blockip as $a) {

         if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == $a) { die(); }

     }



     $mystring = strtoupper($msg);

     foreach ($spam as $a) {

          if (strpos($mystring, strtoupper($a)) === false) {

              /* Everything Ok Here */

          } else {

              die();

          }

     }



     foreach ($espam as $a) {

         if (strtoupper($msg) == strtoupper($a)) { die(); }

     }



     $handle = fopen ($fn, 'r');

     $chattext = fread($handle, filesize($fn)); fclose($handle);



     $arr1 = explode("\n", $chattext);



     if (count($arr1) > $maxlines) {

         /* Pruning */

         $arr1 = array_reverse($arr1);

         for ($i=0; $i<$maxlines; $i++) { $arr2[$i] = $arr1[$i]; }

         $arr2 = array_reverse($arr2);

     } else {

         $arr2 = $arr1;

     }



     $chattext = implode("\n", $arr2);



     // Last spam filter: die if message has already been in the chat history

     if (substr_count($chattext, $msg) > 2) { die(); }



     $spaces = "";

     if (strlen($n) > $nick_maxlength-1) $n = substr($n, 0, $nick_maxlength-1);

     for ($i=0; $i<($nick_maxlength - strlen($n)); $i++) $spaces .= " ";



     $out = $chattext . $n . $spaces . "| " . $msg . "\n";

     $out = str_replace("\'", "'", $out);

     $out = str_replace("\\\"", "\"", $out);



     $handle = fopen ($fn, 'w'); fwrite ($handle, $out); fclose($handle);

 }
```

?>

Answer (score -2):

Para a primeira dúvida, tente por tudo em parágrafos, da seguinte forma:

```
 $linha = "<p>" .$nome. " - " .$mensagem. "<p>";
```

Para a segunda, você podd colocar para apagar TODAS as mensagens com um botão ou a cada X segundos, se preferir. Para isto, utilize o fopen (e converte seu arquivo para txt):

```
setInterval(function(){
$desfaz = fopen("chatlog.txt","w+");
 fclose($desfaz);
}, 300000);
```

Isso fará o arquivo ser recriado (e apagar os registros, lógico) a cada 5 minutos.

Comment: tipo, a ideia é até boa porem,eu gostaria de estar mantendo um historico de 30 linhas das ultimas conversar, eutou pesquisando sobre contar o numero de coringas e deletar a partir dali a ideia de por o <p> vai ser bastante utll

Comment: setInterval no PHP? -1

Comment: Sem contar a ideia de apagar a cada 5 min, que não foi pedido na pergunta -1